# How to access a class inside another DLL?

Tags: c#, dll

I have a chunk of code that I wan't to use on multiple websites. Normally this would be a single class library project, but it involves Entity Framework, so I've split the project into 3 projects wrapped inside its own solution.

I'm currently testing this configuration by referencing the project DLL within my published web application and I've come up against the first hurdle.

In my resuable code, there are 3 projects

BL, DA and Entities

The references are as follows:

BL => DA and Entities
DA => Entities

Entities contains the classes output by EF.

I reference BL.DLL from my web project.

As I've only added the BL.DLL to my web application I can't use the classes created by Entity Framework - is there a way it can be achieved or is there a better model?

Comment: Hey John - have you added references to DA and entities in your project, as well? Like Using BL.DA using BL.DA.Entities? The embedded DLLs for those should be in the BL folder - you would reference in that manner - not individual copies of the DLLs directly to BL

Comment: I've added a reference to BL.DLL then added a using reference in my web page for BL. This is fine, but I can't see the other assembies, DA and Entities, and can't reference in using statements. Of course I could add DA.DLL and Entities.DLL but this kind of defeats the object of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud have one solution with 3 projects inside. Then in your web project add a reference to your Visual Studio projects `Entities` and `BL`.

**References -> Add Reference -> Projects**

Then you will be able to use the `using` statement.

Comment: So, even though I've combined them in a solution, I still need to reference them individually?

Comment: Yes, you have to reference them though they are in the same solution.